# Session closing unexpectedly

Tags: networking, google-chrome, proxy, internet-connection, tls

Forgive my lack of knowledge, as this may be a simple question. Since updating my PC, I am getting the following in chrome when I try to reach certain financial sites.

> This site can’t be reached
>
> lowes.syf.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
>
> Try:
>
> - Checking the connection
> - Checking the proxy and the firewall
>
> ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

And the same with a few others. In IE I get the following:

> Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings and try connecting to https://lowes.syf.com again. If this error persists, it is possible that this site uses an unsupported protocol or cipher suite such as RC4 (link for the details), which is not considered secure. Please contact your site administrator

The companies that I am having these issues with are unable to help me. Neither is my ISP (was wondering if it had something to do with my IP).

I have tried disabling my Norton (after a scan that was negative) and am able to go to these sites fine on my laptop.

Any ideas or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you've tried the TLS settings the IE error recommended?

Comment: Yes I checked them and they are selected.

Comment: Have you checked the time and date on your PC? If they are massively out then the secure connections will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 issues that can be causing it

1. Chrome might need to be reinstalled by removing it and installing a new version
2. Update Chrome to the latest version (RECOMMENDED!!!) <

   Check router settings. There might be a site blacklisted

   The site might be taken down due to some piracy issues. Which happened to the following site.

[image: lowes.com]

Comment: @Mike Crowe When I loaded it on my browser it said it was taken down and theres a reason for it. 1. Piracy issues 2. Innaporiate content such as porn or something 3. Server might be repairing

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  David, I am getting this type of error message on multiple sites.  Also, I have updated Chrome, but I am getting this on Chrome AND IE.  The fact I can browse these multiple sites from my laptop but not my desktop, makes me think its something with my desktop.  I am a novice, so I am not claiming you are wrong and I am right.  Just asking.  Thanks :)